# How to create an excel VBA function for this particular purpose?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create the function for this purpose: I have a year of birth list, I want to take out the last two numbers of that year and make a sum of them. If this sum is less than 10, it will be the result I need. If the result is more than 10 (ex: 9+9 = 18), I will separate this two digits (1 and 8) and make a sum of them (1+8=9. This is less than 10, so it will be my result)

This is my code, but it only give me the result of the first split and sum (18 in this example):

```
Function test(yob as range) as integer
Dim sum, i, j, i2, j2 as integer

i = mid(yob, 3, 1)
j = right(yob, 1)
sum = i + j

If sum < 10 then
     test = sum
Else:
     i2 = left(sum, 1)
     j2 = right(sum, 1)

     test = i2 + j2
End If

End function
```

Comment: use while loop or a recursive function.

Comment: Can you make it more specific, I am pretty new to VBA and programing. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Sub test()

        Debug.Print getSum(9, 9)
        '/ Prints 9
        Debug.Print getSumShort(7, 7)
        '/ Prints 5

    End Sub

    Public Function getSum(x As Long, y As Long)

        Dim res     As Long

        res = x + y

        Do While res > 10 '/ Keep repeating till its greater than 10
          res = (res \ 10) + (res Mod 10)
        Loop

        getSum = res

    End Function

'/ Another way using 9 as divider. 
Public Function getSumShort(x As Long, y As Long)

    Dim res     As Long

    res = (x + y) Mod 9
    getSum = IIf(res = 0, 9, res)

End Function
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Function sum2d(year)
    sum2d=IIf(year mod 100, (year - 1) Mod 9 + 1, 0)
End Function

Sub Test
    For Each v in Array(1980, 2001, 2017)
        Debug.Print v; "=>"; sum2d(v)
    Next
Next
```